# ios linkedIn oauth no success message

Tags: ios, oauth, uiwebview, linkedin-api

I downloaded a sample from https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone. The sample works fine, but I need my write my own authorization, so I created UIWebView and put a breakpoint in

> -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

when I type my login and password returns this
[image: linkedIn answer]

Does anyone know why I don't receive success message in shouldStartLoadWithRequest? It just downloads without stopping on breakpoint, although I stopped on breakpoint before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake, instead of -shouldStartLoadWithRequest I should have looked at -webViewDidFinishLoad. This is a solution